# Angular still load all module in spite of using lazy-loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

As the title. Even though I used lazy-loading for modules but when I open any page it also loads all the remaining modules. I do not even know what default~ module is what file?. Someone knows why. Pls help me.
Thanks for all.

[My network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omqzn.png)
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZF07.png)

Update question: I add lazy-loading follow these step:

- First: I have three children module:

```html
// admin module


import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AdminRouts} from './admin.routing';

import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {DeviceService} from '../../../services/device/device.service';
import {UserService} from '../../../services/user/user.service';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {AccountService} from '../../../services/account/account.service';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';

import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {NgxMaterialTimepickerModule} from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
import {NgMultiSelectDropDownModule} from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MaterialFileInputModule } from 'ngx-material-file-input';
import {DatePickerModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import {DropDownsModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';

import { ZoneMapComponent } from './detail/zone-map/zone-map.component';
import {DetailGroupComponent} from './detail/detail-group/detail-group.component';
import {DetailDeviceComponent} from './detail/detail-device/detail-device.component';
import {DetailDriverComponent} from './detail/detail-driver/detail-driver.component';
import {DetailMaintenanceComponent} from './detail/detail-maintenance/detail-maintenance.component';
import {DetailStatusCodeComponent} from './detail/detail-status-code/detail-status-code.component';
import {DetailUserComponent} from './detail/detail-user/detail-user.component';
import {DetailGeozoneComponent} from './detail/detail-geozone/detail-geozone.component';
import {DetailRoleComponent} from './detail/detail-role/detail-role.component';
import {DetailRuleComponent} from './detail/detail-rule/detail-rule.component';
import {DetailScheduleComponent} from './detail/detail-schedule/detail-schedule.component';
import {DetailAccountComponent} from './detail/detail-account/detail-account.component';
import {ErrorDialogComponent} from './dialog/error.dialog.component';
import { DialogMaintenanceComponent } from './detail/dialog-maintenance/dialog-maintenance.component';
import { DialogMaintenanceExecuteComponent } from './detail/dialog-maintenance-execute/dialog-maintenance-execute.component';
import { DetailSysadminComponent } from './detail/detail-sysadmin/detail-sysadmin.component';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(AdminRouts),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatCardModule,
        TranslateModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
        NgMultiSelectDropDownModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MaterialFileInputModule,
        DatePickerModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        DateInputsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DetailGroupComponent,
        DetailDeviceComponent,
        DetailDriverComponent,
        DetailMaintenanceComponent,
        DetailStatusCodeComponent,
        DetailUserComponent,
        DetailGeozoneComponent,
        DetailRoleComponent,
        DetailRuleComponent,
        DetailScheduleComponent,
        ErrorDialogComponent,
        DetailAccountComponent,
        DetailSysadminComponent,
        DialogMaintenanceComponent,
        DialogMaintenanceExecuteComponent,
        ZoneMapComponent],
    providers: [DeviceService, UserService, AccountService],
    entryComponents: [ErrorDialogComponent]
})
export class AdminModule {
}
```

```html
// report module 


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReportRouts } from './report.routing';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DeviceService } from '../../../services/device/device.service';
import { ReportService } from '../../../services/report/report.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {NgMultiSelectDropDownModule} from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {NgxMaterialTimepickerModule} from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS} from '@angular/material/core';
import { AppDateAdapter, APP_DATE_FORMATS } from './config/format-datepicker';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { SelectColumnsComponent } from './dialog/select-columns/select-columns.component';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { PopupModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-popup';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import {DropDownsModule, SharedModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import 'hammerjs';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, SelectColumnsComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ReportRouts),
        FormsModule,
        TranslateModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        NgMultiSelectDropDownModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatInputModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        PopupModule,
        DateInputsModule,
        // BrowserAnimationsModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        SharedModule,
        GridModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule
    ],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: APP_DATE_FORMATS},
    DeviceService,
    ReportService],
})
export class ReportModule { }
```

```html
// dashboard module

import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {DashboardRoutes} from './dashboard.routing';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {WidgetComponent} from './widget/widget.component';
import {PerformanceComponent} from './performance/performance.component';
import {DropDownsModule, SharedModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import {FilterVehicleDashboardPipe} from '../services/filter/filter-vehicle-dashboard.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        WidgetComponent,
        PerformanceComponent,
        FilterVehicleDashboardPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(DashboardRoutes),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        DateInputsModule
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule {
}
```

- Next I import it on app routing

```html
// app-routings

import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: () => import('./@pages/pages/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'report',
        loadChildren: () => import('./@pages/pages/report/report.module').then(m => m.ReportModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'session',
        loadChildren: () => import('./session/session.module').then(m => m.SessionModule)
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,  { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class RoutingModule {
}
```

And this is my app.module

```html
// app.module

import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {RoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {LoadingBarRouterModule} from '@ngx-loading-bar/router';
import {AuthService} from './services/auth-service/auth.service';
import {GeneAppComponent} from './app.component';
import {MainComponent} from './main/main.component';
import {AuthGuard} from './core/guards/auth.guard';
import {HorizontalMenuItems} from './core/menu/horizontal-menu-items/horizontal-menu-items';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpInterceptorService} from './services/http-interceptor/http-interceptor.service';
import { LayoutComponent } from './@pages/pages/admin/layout/layout.component';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RoutingModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        MatButtonModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        LoadingBarRouterModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        GeneAppComponent,
        MainComponent,
        LayoutComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [GeneAppComponent],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        {
            provide: LocationStrategy,
            useClass: HashLocationStrategy
        },
        AuthGuard,
        HorizontalMenuItems,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class GeneAppModule {
}
```

Comment: Check your imports.

Comment: Are you importing these modules in the appModule?

Comment: How did you use lazy-loading? Please edit the question with all the info needed.

Comment: check if you are importing these modules in another module. If so it would break the lazy loading feature. Are you using a way to preloadModules like Quicklink?

Comment: I've just checked all my module file and update my question. There is no module inner other modules

Comment: @GérômeGrignon no I didn't use it or other like this

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?